# Spring Kafka Listening to all partitions -NumberFormatException

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

'Am trying to listen to all kafka partitions , in  a Spring Boot app, and use the below code  as documented in [assign-all-parts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#tip-assign-all-parts), however i get the exception as below

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*"
```

Is there any otherway to specify all partitions? Below is what 'am trying to use

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions 
              = @TopicPartition(topic = "${mytopic}", partitionOffsets = {
              @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "0")}),groupId ="${mygroup}",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory") 

    public void consumeMessages(String message)
```

Comment: Can we see more stack trace around that `NumberFormatException`? Also: are you sure that you use the proper `spring-kafka` version? This feature made it available since `2.6`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1554

Comment: Thanks very much for reaching out. We are using lower version of spring-kafka (2.5.6), Aplogies for not checking my version, before raising this question!!.

Comment: Glad to see that we are on the same page! Please, close your question since it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Artem Bilan, we need to be using 2.6. Hence closing this.